# How do I place a div on the right site of a div which has a random width?

Tags: css, css-position

I have a div #1 with a variable width and variable height. Now I want to position a div #2 with fixed width and height next to the right site of #1.

These two divs should be inside another div with width: 100%, because I want to repeat those two divs.

Here is an image (white: div #1, black: div #2):

[image]

How would I do that?

I played around with floating

Comment: Can you show us the code of what you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a flexbox for the rows. I put the width for the white box as inline CSS because I assume it will be calculated somehow in your code.

```css
.container {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 3em;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 4em;
}

.row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.flexible {
  background: white;
}

.fixed {
  background: black;
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flexible" style="width:150px"></div>
    <div class="fixed"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flexible" style="width:500px"></div>
    <div class="fixed"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flexible" style="width:50px"></div>
    <div class="fixed"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I don't have a fixed with for the white divs. They get larger as their content (text) grows.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Use flex.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.secondDiv {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
.div1{
    width: <div1 width>;
    height: <div1 height>;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
}
.div2{
    float: left;
    width: <div2 width>;
    height: <div1 height>;
    background-color: black;
}
```

You should group this two divs (div1 and div2) in another div, inside de container with 100% width:

```
<div id="container" class="container">
    <div id="block1" style="float: left; width: 100%">
         <div id="div1" class="div1">
         </div>  
         <div id="div2" class="div2">
         </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```